# Connect Angular 2 with sails.js

Tags: angular, sails.js

I'm trying to connect my Angular 2 with sails using [angular2-sails](https://github.com/joeherold/angular2-sails) using the following line:

```
this.sailor = this._sailsService.connect("http://localhost:1337");
```

I did import sails.io.js in my angular 2 appplication index.html:

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/sails.io.js"></script>
```

Added SailsModule in my app.module.ts:

```
    import {SailsModule} from "angular2-sails";
..
    SailsModule.forRoot(
```

And in my component:

```
import {SailsService} from "angular2-sails";
...
constructor(private _sailsService:SailsService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._sailsService.connect("http://localhost:1337");
  }
```

but the browser return errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    polyfills.js:3 GET http://localhost:8100/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.13.8&__sails_io_s…owser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LluuhLV 404 (Not Found)
    e @ polyfills.js:3
    t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
    n.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
    n.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.js:3
    (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
    send @ VM944:3
    f.create @ sails.io.js:14
    f @ sails.io.js:14
    e.request @ sails.io.js:14
    e.doPoll @ sails.io.js:14
    d.poll @ sails.io.js:14
    d.doOpen @ sails.io.js:14
    d.open @ sails.io.js:14
    d.open @ sails.io.js:14
    d @ sails.io.js:14
    d @ sails.io.js:14
    d.open.d.connect @ sails.io.js:15
    d @ sails.io.js:15
    d @ sails.io.js:15
    d @ sails.io.js:15
    goAheadAndActuallyConnect @ sails.io.js:853
    selfInvoking @ sails.io.js:830
    SailsIOClient.SailsSocket._connect @ sails.io.js:849
    (anonymous) @ sails.io.js:1481
    sails.service.js:172 Client has connected to the server!
    sails.io.js:438 

      |>    Now connected to Sails.
    \___/   For help, see: 
            (using sails.io.js browser SDK @v0.13.8)



    sails.io.js:438  
            Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
    _-|>_-  (attempt #1)
```

Not sure if there is anything to do with it, but I'm using Ionic 2 (cordova)
What's wrong?

Comment: Have you checkd `node-modules` whether `angular2-sails` package is installed properly or not ?

Comment: @TheDictator if it wasn't installed I couldn't import the SailsModule, but I did. I updated my question with my installation steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after this line `<script src="/assets/scripts/sails.io.js"></script>`
add below line, it resolve the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">io.sails.autoConnect=false;</script>
```